# Why the page loads faster after clicking on the URL and pressing Enter

Tags: browser, search-engine, address-bar

Sometimes, when a page takes a lot of time to load, I just click the URL in the address bar and press Enter again. Then, it impressively loads really faster.

Also, the same thing happens when the page didn't load at all even if the URL is manually written correctly, I just search for the name of the page in Google and click the link from the results then it works normally.
How can you explain these behaviors ?
( I am using Firefox at the moment but it also happened in Chrome )

Comment: Proably because the content of the page has already been loaded and is cached - so there is not the need to download evertyhing again from the server or external API. Open the console and view the sources and the HTTP response codes  to check that.

Comment: But if the cache is stored, it means the page has to load after storing it ( at the first load ) but it loads forever. so I solve the problem by selecting the URL and pressing Enter again to reload the page ( I don't use the reload button because it doesn't work sometimes ).